# Autohotkey Add Javascript Hash To Local URL

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere.

I have a script that opens a file with an acronym search page, but I want to append a ? and the clipboard contents to the URL (the page grabs the passed argument and searches it).  This is what I have now, but it just opens the page.  It's probably something dead simple.

```
#w::
    Run, file:%A_Desktop%\html\acronym.html?%Clipboard%
return
```

Comment: You code works for me. I would remove the file: and check the clipboard contents.

Comment: Please post the contents of `acronym.html`.

Answer (score 1):

`A_Desktop` is the full path to your desktop ie. `C:\Users\username\Desktop\`

Try removing the `file:` in front.

**EDIT:**

This worked for me in Chrome and IE. It looks like you may not have had the right number of slashes as well as in the incorrect direction.

```
#w::
    Run % "file:///" . RegExReplace(A_Desktop "\test.html?" clipboard, "(\\)", "/")
Return
```

Comment: file: is what got it to work in the first place.  It's just not picking up the ?%Clipboard

Comment: When I run your edited script with my path, it still does the same thing - opens IE with just the URL, no ? and clipboard content attached.  The slashes they still default to \ no matter what.

I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm using AHK Version 1.0.48.05, Windows XP Pro SP3 32-bit, IE 8.0.6001.18702CO.

Comment: That might be the issue.  I am running the latest [AHK_L](http://l.autohotkey.net/AutoHotkey_L_Install.exe)

Comment: Hmm, I downloaded v1.1.11.01 and it still does the same thing as before.  Work has a many of the download sites blocked, so that was about the only portable version I could find.